# JBoss AS7 JNDI Datasources for JPA on shared server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, jndi

Q: How do I prevent another developer from using my database credentials setup in a datasource in standalone.xml?

I'm trying to setup JPA for intranet/internal apps on JBoss.

Looks like the standard is JNDI within standalone.xml, configured either with the web console or cli.  Using a datasource configured on the server makes sense since as a developer in my persistence unit I would just have to reference a name, say "EmployeeDb" and then the appropriate URL and credentials are setup on each JBoss instance.  This makes deploying the same WAR across DEV/STAGE/PROD work without modification. With our CM process I can only modify code residing on DEV.

But right off the bat this requires the JBoss admin (a contractor) to know my db credentials.

Secondly isn't this global datasource available to other developer's apps?  How do I prevent another developer from using my datasource?  If a datasource that connects to sensitive or privileged company data is setup in standalone.xml, is it going to be available to other developers, who can (I guess they would have to guess the name of my DS) query the sensitive data. Also, the contractors managing JBoss would have access to this sensitive data. I am aware that the passwords in standalone.xml can be encrypted but wouldn't the datasource still be accessible to other deployed apps?

How do other developers/companies handle JPA in this type of environment, where there are multiple employees developing internal apps on DEV and deployed to STAGE/PROD servers by a CM group?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you can't. If you can't trust the code you're deploying then don't deploy it.

Comment: My code provides application logic for determining access levels to the database.  If another developer can use my JNDI datasource name, then they can write code which bypasses my application logic for db access.  Sounds like I would need to deploy only 1 app per JBoss instance.